# How to loop an imported VDB file

Tags: volumetrics

Is there any way to loop an imported VDB file? I've imported a VDB that is set up to be looped from Janga FX. It is only 128 frames long, but I want to make it loop multiple times in Blender 3.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Troy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Volume Data** change the **Mode** to **Repeat** or **Ping-Pong** depending of the type of the simulation or the effect you want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I missed the obvious.